# SQL Server Express Connection String - Unusual Parameter

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I've inherited a web app, the local testing version has the following parameter on the end of its connection string:

```
;Database=ServiceDelivery;LastUser=sa
```

Can someone explain to me what "LastUser=sa" means? I know the sa account, but have never come across LastUser before.

Googling it hasn't produced any results.

Comment: Supposedly it's not used any more: http://www.installaware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8597

Comment: Agreed, want to add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's not used any more:

http://www.installaware.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8597